# Ajax in a wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to use the following piece of ajax jquery in a WordPress page:

```
  1.  <script>
  2.  $(document).ready(function(){
  3.     $("button").click(function(){
  4.      $.ajax({
  5.          method: 'GET',
  6.          url: "http:Sample.url.com",}).done(function (data)
  7.              {
  8.            var f_table= "";
  9.            for (var i = 0; i < data.unittopics.topics.length; i++) {
  10.           f_table+= "<tr><td>" +data.unittopics.topics[i].name+  "</td><td>" +data.unittopics.topics[i].description+ "</td><td>" + "<a id=" +'Frac_Link'+i+ " href='#'>" +'Click here'+  "</td></tr>";
  11.           alert("#div"+data.unittopics.topics[i].id);
            }
  12.  $("#Frac_Table").append(f_table);
  13.       for (var x = 0; x < data.unittopics.topics.length; x++) 
 {
  14.   $("#Frac_Link"+x).attr('href', data.unittopics.topics[x].externalUrl);
  alert("working");
 }

});
});
});
</script>
```

I have tested this a jquery in w3school testing environment and it work perfect, but when I put it into WordPress it throws the following error `Invalid or unexpected token` on row **10.** is there a simple way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Tell jQuery that it should attach itself to the `$` namespace by using `$jQuery(document).ready(function($){` on the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above are correct and solved another problem I didn't know I had. 
But the problem I posted about was resolved my separating the `<tr><td>` tags in my jQuery.

**solution**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#frac_btn").one('click', function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http:Sample.url.com'
    }).done(
      function (data) {
        var f_table= "";

        for (var i = 0; i < data.unittopics.topics.length; i++) {
          f_table += '<tr' + '><td' + '>' +
            data.unittopics.topics[i].name + '</td' + '><td' + '>' +
            data.unittopics.topics[i].description + '</td' + '><td' + '>' +
            '<a id=' + 'Frac_Link' + i + " href='#'>" + 'Click here' +
            '</td' + '></tr' + '>';
        }

        jQuery("#Frac_Table").append(f_table);

        for (var x = 0; x < data.unittopics.topics.length; x++) {
          jQuery('#Frac_Link' + x).attr('href', data.unittopics.topics[x].externalUrl);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and I changed 
$ 
to 
jQuery 
which worked for me

Comment: Where would I need to change the $ to jQuery ?

Comment: All jquery references,  like $("#Frac_Table") to jQuery("#Frac_Table") and every $ to jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress runs with jQuery in no-conflict mode, so replaces the use of `$` with `jQuery`, so either, replace all instances of `$` with `jQuery`, or...

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

That should fix it.